# How to call nested object list on table list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom

Hi im newbie on react js,

how to call nested object(array/list) on main object, i mean object in object

```
 <tbody>
      {
        vehicles.map((v, index) =>(
          <tr key={v.id}>
            <td>{index +1}</td>
            <td>{v.type}</td>
            <td>{v.plateNumber}</td>
            {v.employee.map(item => {
                return (
                  <td>
                  <ul>{item.name}</ul>
                  </td>
                  );
            })}
            <td>
                <Link className="btn btn-info" to={`/vehicles/edit/${v.id}`}>Update</Link>
                <button className="btn btn-danger ml-2" onClick={() => {deleteSweetAlert(v.id)}}>Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))
      }
      </tbody>
```

This one my JSON example

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "MasterCard",
        "plateNumber": "3747948",
        "status": "1",
        "employee": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joanne Hagenes Sr.",
            "location": "60794 Rippin Cove Suite 080\nTroyberg, ND 95778",
            "department": "Wuckert-Luettgen",
            "status": "1"
        }
    }
]
```

I always get this error message at the console

***react-dom.development.js:26874 Uncaught TypeError: v.employee.map is not a function***

Comment: The issue happened because the `employee` key has an object as value, not an array, and `map` method works for arrays. To iterate through `employee` object keys you should use - [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). But most probably you don't even need to iterate. Just use `v.employee.name`

Comment: `employee` is an object instead of array. If you only need the name property then use it like `<td> <ul>{v.employee.name}</ul> </td>`
Map does not work for object.

Answer (score 0):

`map()` function can only applied with an array, so in your case `employee` should be an array instead an object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "MasterCard",
    "plateNumber": "3747948",
    "status": "1",
    "employee": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Joanne Hagenes Sr.",
        "location": "60794 Rippin Cove Suite 080\nTroyberg, ND 95778",
        "department": "Wuckert-Luettgen",
        "status": "1"
    }]
}
```

Another way to fix this, since each of your `vehicle` contains only 1 `employee` (based on how u named it). So i suppose you dont need to use `map()` function in this case:

```
 <tbody>
  {
    vehicles.map((v, index) =>(
      <tr key={v.id}>
        <td>{index +1}</td>
        <td>{v.type}</td>
        <td>{v.plateNumber}</td>
        <td>
              <ul>{item.name}</ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <Link className="btn btn-info" to={`/vehicles/edit/${v.id}`}>Update</Link>
            <button className="btn btn-danger ml-2" onClick={() => {deleteSweetAlert(v.id)}}>Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))
  }
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface to define.

```
interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
}
interface IBaz {
  baz: string;
  foo: IFoo;
}

const obj: IBaz = {
  baz: 'bar',
  foo: {
    foo: 'foo',
  },
};

console.log(obj.baz); // -> baz
console.log(obj.foo.foo); // -> foo
```